# How to correctly scale an ImageView in a widget?

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap, widget

I have two images overlayed on top of another in a widget layout. The top image is supposed to rotate above the background image. Both are ImageViews. As you can see, the inside circle is too small (check [xkcd.com/now](http://xkcd.com/now) to see what the layout should look like) . I tried resizing the file itself, which didn't change anything, I tried using `mat.postScale`, which only gave me an outOfMemory error. I'm using `matrix.postRotate` to rotate the inside circle. Since I'm using `RemoteViews` (it's a widget), I'm very limited in what I can do. So how can I resize the inside circle by 115%? (oh and I can't use fixed values because it has to change sizes if the widget is resized)

And here is the XML layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription = "@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/imagef"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription = "@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/nowView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Screenshot of what it looks like now:

[image: the inside circle is slightly too small]

Comment: Set the container to fill parent or something and then use Weights on those ImageViews (Use LinearLayout)

Comment: can I overlay the two images in a LinearLayout? I'm using a RelativeLayout right now

Comment: Please try using a LinearLayout.

Comment: I did, the top image disappears offscreen. Since there is no `centerInParent` in LinearLayouts.